# Highlight the shift button on the keyboard when an UIAlertView pops up

Tags: ios6, uialertview, uikeyboard

I have a UIAlertView

```
UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput
```

that I'm using to add things to a TableView. Nothing crazy, it's just a list of things the user can add to. It would look nicer with the first letters capitalized. I don't want to automatically capitalize whats in the text field. I just want the keyboard to pop up with the shift key highlighted. I tried switching the keyboard to `UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad`. But that didn't work. I also noticed in the app store on my Iphone, they use the same UIAlertView and there is no shift highlighted. So maybe it's not possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Err. Sorry, I didn't know you had to do it through the textfield, I thought it was some sort of keyboard option.

```
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
[alert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
```